# Same macro is not working in different sheets in excel with command button

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a forecasting template for different channels say channel1, channel2 & channel3
Now I want to keep the same VBA code for these 3 channels (in 3 different sheet/tabs of excel), which is working fine for `sheet1` but it's giving different result for `sheet2` & `sheet3`. Have written same macro for three different sheets ( as the inputs & output would change for channels), which are connected to command buttons at these 3 sheets.
The code along with the image :
[enter image description here][1]

```
Sub Macro1()
' Example Solver VBA Macro
    SolverReset
           SolverOk SetCell:="$L$7", _
             MaxMinVal:=2, _
             ValueOf:="0", _
             ByChange:="$G$4:$G$6"
           SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$7", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
End Sub
```

so basically I'm trying to assign weights which would generate minimum error and the sum of weights would be 1. Now `sheet1` is working fine but for `sheet 2` & `sheet 3` , sum of the weights are not unity (though the code is same)

Comment: Don't post code images - type the code in. People won't help you as readily if they have to type the code from an image. Edit your post with the code in the text.

Comment: Could someone help me regarding this ?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do and where your issue is. Although you didn't ask a question yet.

Comment: I was trying to write the VBA code for excel sheet with different tabs; in first tab it's working fine but for the rest of the tabs it's not working. The code has been mentioned above. I just wanted to know the changes needed in the codes so that it would work with all the sheets of the excel sheet. Surprisingly it seems some part of the code     SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$7", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"   --> is not working

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same (or at least similar issue), where my solver code worked in one sheet (usually the one that is open/active when the code is created) but didn't in other worksheets (created by copying the initial one). In my case, the same code is called by a button in each sheet.
Long story short, the solver constraints are in some weird way connected to the original worksheet (let's say "Sheet1").

My solution comes in 2 steps:

1. The solver needs to run once (every time after opening) before it is called by the procedure. For this, I recorded the macro (in sheet1) and inserted it in the Sub "Workbook_Open". (i added a message box to tell the user what's going on).
2. I created (in a separate sheet called "Solversheet") a few cells where the code writes the parameters of the solver. I had to do this, because my solver solves one line at a time and the constraints have to change accordingly. 
   After that, the parameters can be loaded by SolverLoad from this separate worksheet, no matter from which worksheet you are working in. (If the code was not run once before this procedure, you will probably receive an Error at this point)

Here's my code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 j = InputBox("Please enter the row in which the table starts (Pkt = 1)", , 13)
 n = InputBox("Please enter the last row for which the solver should solve")

     For i = j To n

               'Sets the solver parameters for each solver
               Range("SOLVERSHEET!B2").Value = "=MIN($I$" & i & ")"
               Range("SOLVERSHEET!B3").Value = "=COUNT($I$" & i & ")"
               Range("SOLVERSHEET!B4").Value = "=$CD$" & i & "<=1"
               Range("SOLVERSHEET!B5").Value = "=$CE$" & i & "<=1"

           SolverLoad ("SOLVERSHEET!B2:B5")
       '    SolverOk SetCell:=Range("I" & i), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range("I" & i), Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
           SolverSolve True

          Range("I" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Range("I" & i), 0)

     Next i

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Note that the range for "SolverLoad" will depend on the amount of constraints.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that you could test, this fixes the error 438 mentioned in the above answer.  Try to eliminate the form button, and replace it with a text box.  Once the box is placed, right click it and then set "Assign Macro" similar to what you would do for a form control.  This seems to allow for a "button", in this case the text box, to link to the macro that uses solver functions.  But copying the sheet with this text box doesn't break the SolverLoad function.